# Help with algebra sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone help me with this, please?

Let $A, B$ be sets. Show the following is true:
$$P(A) \cup P(B) \subseteq P(A \cup B)$$

$P$ is a powerset.

Do I just expand $P(A \cup B)$ to $P(A) \cup P(B)$?

$$P(A) \cup P(B) \subseteq P(A) \cup P(B)$$

So therefore it's true?

Seems too simple.

Comment: An element of $P(A)\cup P(B)$ is either a subset of $A$ or a subset of $B$. So it is a subset also of …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $P(A\cup B)$ is the powerset of $A\cup B$, i.e. the set of all subsets of $A\cup B$. So we don't have $P(A\cup B)=P(A)\cup P(B)$, only the containment
$$P(A)\cup P(B)\ \,\subset\ \,P(A\cup B)\,.$$
For example take $A:=\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $B:=\{b_1,b_2\}$, then $\{a_1,b_1\}\ \in\ P(A\cup B)\,\setminus\,\left(P(A)\cup P(B)\right)$.

Comment: You know a lot, being a cat and all.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Don't be ridiculous! You haven't changed your gravatar yet.